# Gathering values from sub objects in Vue.JS and assigning to parent object key

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuejs2

Here's what the data "valueContainer" looks like:

```
{
         "totalValue": 0,
         "subValues1": [
           { "value": 20 },{ "value": 30 }
         ],
         "subValues2": [
           { "value": 10 },{ "value": 40 }
         ]
        }
```

I'm trying to gather the values from 'subValues1' and 'subValues2' and store them in the 'totalValue' field? I've been trying to use computed but the for loop isn't working, here's an example of trying to accumulate values from the first sub object

```
  computed: {
    totalValue: function() {
      let total;
      for (let v in this.valueContainer.subValues1) {
        total = total + v.value;
      }
      return total;
    }
  }
```

As written I'm getting NaN for the totalValue. How can I loop through the values, accumulate the values, and store them as totalValue?

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/connorontheweb/pen/dyPvwmE

Comment: `subValues1` and `subValues2` should be arrays.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. It actually is an array, editing now

Comment: Your data is not valid javascript btw. Can you create a codepen?

Comment: Here it is: https://codepen.io/connorontheweb/pen/dyPvwmE

Comment: for...in loop iterates on the array indexes not the value.

Comment: Yes but I should be able to access a value from each index, right?

Comment: yes you can access the value like so `this.valueContainer.subValues1[v]`, or use other iterations like for...of loop, Array.forEach

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the keys, filter by unwanted and iterate the values arrays. Then add the values to total.

```js
var data = { valueContainer: { totalValue: 0, subValues1: [{ value: 20 }, { value: 30 }], subValues2: [{ value: 10 }, { value: 40 }] } };

Object
    .keys(data.valueContainer)
    .filter(v => v !== 'totalValue')
    .forEach(k => data.valueContainer[k].forEach(({ value }) => data.valueContainer.totalValue += value));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working component:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ totalValue }}</div>
</template>
```

```js
const sum = list => list.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      valueContainer: {
        subValues1: [{ value: 20 }, { value: 30 }],
        subValues2: [{ value: 10 }, { value: 40 }],
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    totalValue() {
      const { subValues1, subValues2 } = this.valueContainer;
      const values = [...subValues1, ...subValues2].map(({ value }) => value);
      return sum(values);
    },
  },
};
```

If you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you could simplify this a bit with `sumBy`:

```js
import sumBy from 'lodash/sumBy';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      valueContainer: {
        subValues1: [{ value: 20 }, { value: 30 }],
        subValues2: [{ value: 10 }, { value: 40 }],
      },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    totalValue() {
      const { subValues1, subValues2 } = this.valueContainer;
      return sumBy([...subValues1, ...subValues2], 'value');
    },
  },
};
```